# PHP need a fix to a small form submit validation bug

Tags: php, forms, validation

OK, when I submit my form, it will check for pregmatch (only letters and white space allowed) but, it will submit the form anyway (if all form fields have data)... I need to add something to my code that says, yes all your fields are filled out but you still have errors. So I will not submit. how can I reconfigure my submit validation to fix this small bug

```php
<?php
  $e_first = ""; $e_last = ""; $e_email = ""; $success = "";
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    require_once("config.php");
    require_once("database.php");
    require_once("controller.php");

    $firstname = sanitize($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = sanitize($_POST['lastname']);
    $email = sanitize($_POST['email']);
    $submit = sanitize($_POST['submit']);

    if (empty($firstname)) {
      $e_first = "First Name is required";
    } else {
      $firstname;
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $firstname)) {
        $e_first = "Only letters and white space allowed";
      }
    }

    if (empty($lastname)) {
      $e_last = "Last Name is required";
    } else {
      $lastname;
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $lastname)) {
        $e_last = "Only letters and white space allowed";
      }
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
      $e_email = "Email Address is required";
    } else {
      $email;
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $e_email = "Invalid Email Address";
      }
    }

    $users = [
      'firstname' => $firstname,
      'lastname' => $lastname,
      'email' => $email
    ];

    if (isset($submit)) {
      switch (false) {
        case !empty($firstname) || $firstname == $e_first :
          $success = "";
        break;
        case !empty($lastname) || $lastname == $e_last :
          $success = "";
        break;
        case !empty($email) || $email == $e_email :
          $success = "";
          break;
        default :
          $control = new Controller();
          $control->addCustomer($users);
          header("Location: success.php");
          break;
      }
    } 

  }

  function sanitize($data) {
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = trim($data);
    return $data;
  }

?>
```

this is the form

```html
    <section class="form_box">
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
        <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $e_first; ?></span>
        <input type="text" class="input" name="firstname" id="firstname"/>

        <label for="lastname">First Last:</label>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $e_last; ?></span>
        <input type="text" class="input" name="lastname" id="lastname"/>

        <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $e_email; ?></span>
        <input type="email" class="input" name="email" id="email"/>

        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        <span class="success"><?php echo $success; ?></span>
      </form>
    </section>
```

any thoughts... thanks

Comment: `sanitize()` < that function with the other functions won't do much for an SQL injection. Do yourself a favor and use a prepared statement instead.

Comment: The `switch` statement is really confusing, I can't figure it its logic. It would be so much easier if you wrote an ordinary `if/elseif/else`.

Comment: `$firstname == $e_first` makes no sense, there's nothing that ever sets the two variables equal to each other. `$e_first` is either empty or it contains an error message.

Comment: Try to learn about `try-catch` block and how to throw an exception. That would be handy to break flow when error happens

Comment: You probably just want something like `if (empty($e_first) && empty($e_last) && empty($e_email)) { submit form } else { report errors }`

Comment: @Anggara Exceptions are overkill for simple form validation. Nothing in the process warrants having an entire stack trace, especially if you won't be using it. Additionally, a form should be validated all the way through, instead of it being interrupted only to present the next error to the user on next submit. The user should see all the form errors immediately.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, thanks for your feedback, I really have a passion for code and doing everything I can to learn everyday. I learned about SQL injections so I use the PDO object in the background and use a controller to communicate with both the database and form submit, any information I get will be much appreciated, the backend is challenging and that's what I love about it

Comment: @Barmar, yea this part of my code logic is what I came up with when I was testing for submit errors. I really do wish I could have started learning to code back in the 1990's so I wont have any of these issues with my logic. but I am here to learn, so any help is much appreciated. looking at your if statement, I tried using && but the condition is only met if all is true. so || was more flexible when checking the conditions of the form submit. I do need to change the logic because it is not sound. If its not asking to much would it be ok for me to ask you to post another example... Thanks

Comment: All the inputs are required and have to be proper format. `&&` is the correct condition.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for your feedback, I do need a mentor that can advise me every now and then. what do you think about theses changes I made

Comment: @Barmar
```php
    if (isset($submit)) {
      $errors = [];
      $validate = true;

      if (!isset($firstname) || empty($firstname) || $firstname == $e_first) {
        $validate = false;
        $error[$firstname] = $submit = "";
      }
      if (!isset($lastname) || empty($lastname) || $lastname == $e_last) {
        $validate = false;
        $error[$lastname] = $submit = "";
      }
      if (!isset($email) || empty($email) || $email == $e_email) {
        // your code
      }

      if ($validate) {
        // your code
      }
    }
```